# How to keep a variable in the URL when using Spring LocaleChangeInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a page at this URL `http://localhost:8080/SpringExercises/admin/manageMenuDetail?id=1`.

I use Spring LocaleChangeInterceptor to handle languages.

When I try to change the language by clicking on a link like `"?lang=it"` I get an error, because `id` is null.

I suppose Spring turns `.../SpringExercises/admin/manageMenuDetail?id=1`
 into
 `.../SpringExercises/admin/manageMenuDetail?lang=it` forgetting to write `?id=1`

Can Spring handles this problem (for example editing the configuration file) or have I to handle it by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you clicked a link with "http://xxx?lang=it"? If so, you should handle by yourself. eg. you could add a data-lang attribute, by that, add current href, like that: location.href = location.href + $("xx").data("lang");